# Cannot find name 'ENV' returnTo: ENV.BASE_URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, auth0

I assume my authentication service fails to load a configuration file causing an error.
Im following along a tutorial on AUTH0.Here is the link https://auth0.com/blog/real-world-angular-series-part-2/.
I have to import a file from env.config.ts that will be used by my authentication service.Here is the code **env.config.ts**

```
const _isDev = window.location.port.indexOf('4200') > -1;
const getHost = () => {
  const protocol = window.location.protocol;
  const host = window.location.host;
  return `${protocol}//${host}`;
};
const apiURI = _isDev ? 'http://localhost:8083/api/' : `/api/`;

export const ENV = {
  BASE_URI: getHost(),
  BASE_API: apiURI
};
```

Here is a quote from the tutorial "This code detects the host environment and sets the app's base URI and base API URI. We'll import this ENV configuration wherever we need to detect and use these URIs."
This **env** file is imported into a file required by auth0,
Here is my snippet of the **auth.config.ts**

```
import { ENV } from './../core/env.config';

interface AuthConfig {
  CLIENT_ID: string;
  CLIENT_DOMAIN: string;
  AUDIENCE: string;
  REDIRECT: string;
  SCOPE: string;
  NAMESPACE: string;
};

export const AUTH_CONFIG: AuthConfig = {
  CLIENT_ID: '[xxx]',
  CLIENT_DOMAIN: '[]', // e.g., kmaida.auth0.com
  AUDIENCE: '[http://localhost:8083/api/]', // e.g., http://localhost:8083/api/
  REDIRECT: `${ENV.BASE_URI}/callback`,
  SCOPE: 'openid profile email',
  NAMESPACE: 'http://myapp.com/roles'
};
```

Please have a look at the tutorial and maybe share what i could have missed.

The **auth.service.ts** uses the configutaion file as such

```
   // Remove data from localStorage
    this._clearExpiration();
    this._clearRedirect();
    // End Auth0 authentication session
    this._auth0.logout({
      clientId: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_ID,
      returnTo: ENV.BASE_URI
    });
  }
```

this is what my imports section looks like of  **auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth.config';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { ENV } from './../core/env.config';
```

The error emmited in my cmd reads

> ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.service.ts:92:17 - error TS2304: Cannot find name >'ENV'.
>
> 92       returnTo: ENV.BASE_URI.
>   I also suspect the way the imports are handled from core have a problem ,as i really im not well vast with the slash imports.
>   I have my app directory that holds the auth and core folder as direct children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try declaring ENV inside a constructor.

```
public constructor(){
const env = ENV
}
```

Then use it.

```
console.log(env.BASE_URI)
```